# objective C . get lat/lng information on app delegate.m

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager * locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSLog(@"11111");
    CLLocationManager *manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    manager.delegate = self;
     [manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    //Here you set the Distance Filter that you need
    manager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    // Here you set the Accuracy
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    NSLog(@"startUpdatingLocation");
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
    NSLog(@"startUpdatingLocation %@" , status);



    [manager startUpdatingLocation];

     NSLog(@"22222");
    return YES;
}
```

first problem is that popup that asking permission called by 
`[manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];` is dismissed just after 0.5sec~3sec. I don't know why it dismiss.

and even if I pressed always approved (I don't know how English version is exactly), 
`CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];`
status is alway null

```
    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(CLLocation *)newLocation{
//    currentLocation = newLocation;
    NSLog(@"locationinfor %@!   ,,, %@!!!!", newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude);


}
```

Secondly

for this phase, `[manager startUpdatingLocation];`
It should go to `didUpdateLocations` function and should Log 
 `NSLog(@"locationinfor %@!   ,,, %@!!!!", newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude);`
but It doesn't come to `didUpdateLocations`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be your declaration of `CLLocationManager *manager`. When you already have a class member `CLLocationManager *locationManager` defined, why not use that.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSLog(@"11111");
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
     [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    //Here you set the Distance Filter that you need
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    // Here you set the Accuracy
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    NSLog(@"startUpdatingLocation");
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
    NSLog(@"startUpdatingLocation %@" , status);



    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

     NSLog(@"22222");
    return YES;
}
```

Edit : Make sure your Info.plist has descriptive text for User-sensitive data. You could also check for `authorization status` and request again if authorization is undetermined.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
}
```